# Javascript Function Not Getting Called after setFocus() call

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

I am using java-script in my Salesforce application and i am in the middle of a bizarre situation.

I have used the below code in my visualforce page.

```
<script>
    var previousOnLoad = window.onload;
    window.onload = function() {
        if (previousOnLoad) {
            previousOnLoad();
        }

        renderSection('false');
        setFocus();
    }

    function setFocus() {
        document.getElementById("{!$component.thePageBlock.state}").focus()
    }

    function renderSection(input) {
        if (input == true) {
            document.getElementById("{!$component.thePageBlock.theSection}").style.display='block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem that I am facing is after the `setFocus()` function is called the other function `rendersection()` is not called. But when i remove the `setFocus()` and then try, then the `rendersection()` is called. As seen in the above code i have also tried giving the `rendersection()` before the `setFocus()`. still it does not work. Does anyone know if i am missing anything here?

Also, when i tried to change the setFocus() to something different like putFocus or getFocus the function is called but the focus is not set to the desired field.

Thanks

Comment: Are you receiving an error in your javascript debugging console?

Comment: are you sure renderSection is not being called? Or maybe it's being called and just not doing anything. (You're calling it with input='false' and you have the if input == true statement in the function)

Comment: I cross checked by using an alert inside the renderSection() before the if statement. Without the setFocus() the alert pops up, otherwise not. There are also no errors in the console.